# Navigate to a page not in AuthProviderBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using AuthProviderBuilder

```
AuthProviderBuilder(
      builder: (context, user) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'My App',
          theme: ThemeData(),
          home: ScreenRouter(user: user),
        );
      },
    );
```

with screen router

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (user.status) {
      case Status.Unauthenticated:
        return WelcomeScreen();
      case Status.Authenticated:
        return HomeScreen();
      default:
        return SplashScreen();
    }
  }
```

Now how can I navigate from Home screen to different brand new screen on click of a button placed in Home screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to push new rout inside navigation stack. In your new Screen create static function

```
  static Future<void> show(BuildContext context) async {
    await Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MyNewScreenName(), fullscreenDialog: true),
    );
  }
```

and just call it with your button in your home page by

```
onPressed: () => MyNewScreenName.show(context)
```